# In a string containing nested parenthesis, how to obtain the whole parenthesis using str_extract?

Tags: r, string, format

Given a string

```
x <- "Really long (distraction) wine name (Country A)"
```

I'm able to extract `"(Country A)"` using `str_extract(x, '\\([^()]+\\)$')`.

However when it comes to nested parenthesis, such as `"Wine name (Country A (State))"`, running that code gives me `NA`. How can that be avoided and why is it happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `?R` like:

```
x <- c("Really long (distraction) wine name (Country A)"
     , "Wine name (Country A (State))")
regmatches(x, regexpr("(\\(([^()]|(?1))*\\))$", x, perl=TRUE))
#[1] "(Country A)"         "(Country A (State))"
```

Where `a(?1)z` is a recursion which match one or more letters `a` followed by exactly the same number of letters `z`.

Comment: Could add a small explanation? What is the function of `?R`?